# Access React tree from within a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to access the React tree down a component from within it?
For instance when I use the React-devtool extension I am able to navigate along the React tree. Is it possible to do such navigation from within the code of a component to know everything below it?

I know about children, but it does not work when parents components simply render children components, ie in `Parent` component I have something like

```
   render() {
       <Child1 />
   }
```

then in `Child1` component I have

```
   render() {
       <Child2 />
   }
```

etc.

and I'd like to know from `Parent` that there is below a `Child1` and then a `Child2`.

I have had a look at `this._reactInternalInstance._instance._renderedComponent._currentElement` where I can see that, for instance, `Parent` renders a `Child1`. But from this I cannot go further to see what `Child1` renders.

Comment: Why do you need this?
 It looks like [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have deep nested forms and for now I have encapsulated the things like this. Now I would to access from the top component everything what is in the form

Comment: one thing you can do is bubble-up the state from child components to parent so that everything you need is in the parent component.

Comment: I have already one single state for all the hierarchy but when I want to validate the data I need to know whether or not some fields were present in the child components, depending on some conditions written therein

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve a similar problem (needed to access state of a foreign Component's child) with:

```js
return <Child ref={this.childRef} />
```

```js
this.childRef.current._reactInternalFiber.child.child.memoizedState;
```

Hope it helps & YMMV ;)